# Plotting a line with slope 45 degrees

Tags: c++, geometry

This is a homework assignment. I am given the coordinates of my viewport, and the coordinates of a line that is given to be either horizontal, vertical or at 45 degrees.

This is my function to draw the line

```
void DrawLine(int p, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
int row,col;


if( x1 == x2) //vertical
{
    ClipToPanel(panel_top[p][0], panel_top[p][1], panel_bot[p][0], panel_bot[p][1], x1, y1, x2, y2);
 //   cout<<tmpx1<<","<<tmpy1<<" "<<tmpx2<<","<<tmpy2<<endl;

    if(tmpx1==NINF)
        return;
    if(tmpy1 > tmpy2)
        swap(tmpy1,tmpy2);

    col = tmpx1 - panel_top[p][0];
    for(int i = tmpy1 - panel_top[p][1] ; i <= tmpy2 - panel_top[p][1] ; i++)
        panel[p][i][col] = 'x';
}
else if( y1 == y2) //horizontal
{
    ClipToPanel(panel_top[p][0], panel_top[p][1], panel_bot[p][0], panel_bot[p][1], x1, y1, x2, y2);
   // cout<<tmpx1<<","<<tmpy1<<" "<<tmpx2<<","<<tmpy2<<endl;
    if(tmpx1==NINF)
        return;
    if(tmpx1 > tmpx2)
        swap(tmpx1, tmpx2);

    row = tmpy2 - panel_top[p][1];
    for(int j = tmpx1 - panel_top[p][0] ; j <= tmpx2 - panel_top[p][0] ; j++)
        panel[p][row][j] = 'x';
}

else if(abs(x2-x1) == abs(y2-y1)) //45degree line
{
    ClipToPanel(panel_top[p][0], panel_top[p][1], panel_bot[p][0], panel_bot[p][1], x1, y1, x2, y2);
 //   cout<<tmpx1<<","<<tmpy1<<" "<<tmpx2<<","<<tmpy2<<endl;
    if(tmpx1 == NINF)
        return;

    x1 = tmpx1 - panel_top[p][0];
    x2 = tmpx2 - panel_top[p][0];
    y1 = tmpy1 - panel_top[p][1];
    y2 = tmpy2 - panel_top[p][1];
    if(y2 > y1)
    {
        if(x2 > x1)
        {
            for(int i = y1, j = x1 ; i<=y2 ;i++,j++)
                panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = y1, j = x1 ; i <= y2; j--, i++)
                panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(x2>x1)
        {
            for(int i = y1, j = x1 ; i >= y2 ; i--, j++)
                panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = y1, j = x1 ; i >= y2 ; i--, j--)
                panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
        }
    }
}
}
```

The axes are +Y downwards +X towards right.
The viewport and line coordinates can range from -10000 to 10000. I subtract the lower corner to get them in range [0,n] and store in a matrix.
`ClipToPanel()` is the implementation of cohen-sutherland algorithm to clip the line and get the endpoints inside the viewport.
It sets the values if `tmpx1`, `tmpy1`, `tmpx2`, `tmpy2` as the end points of the clipped line.

```
panel_top[p][0] is upper x-coordinate of viewport (xmin)
panel_top[p][1] is upper y-coordinate of viewport (ymin)  
panel_bot[p][0] is lower x-coordinate of viewport (xmax)
panel_bot[p][1] is lower y-coordinate of viewport (ymax)
```

If the line is not in the viewport coords i set `tmpx1`, `tmpx2`, `tmpy2`, `tmpy1` to `NINF`.

I can't seem to find the error. My online judge keeps giving me a wrong answer.

Comment: Have you the input which give wrong ouput ? Are you sure that `ClipToPanel` is correct ?

Comment: Are you sure of the format `panel[p][y][x]` (seems used coherency)

Comment: A good starting point: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I have other functions such as drawRectangle, drawPolygon which use drawline to perform operations and they pass the test. only the drawline test fails. 
im sure of panel[p][y][x] format. p is the index of a panel (there can be multiple panels) y is the row (since +Y axis is downwards) and x is column (+X axis is rightwards)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a comment, but since it contains some code I'll post it as an answer. I think that you can consider the fact of simplifying the diagonals output function, considering that there are basically only two of them:

```
if ( x1 > x2 ) swap(x1,x2);
if ( y2 > y1 ) {
    for(int i = y1, j = x1; j <= x2; i++, j++ )
        panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
} else {
    for(int i = y2, j = x1; j <= x2; i++, j-- )
        panel[p][i][j] = 'x';
}
```

It could be usefull to know what values do you get for your variables.